# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work added to an UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tap

I'm triyng to make a gesture recognizer for a simple UIView:

```
UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[theView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                       action:@selector(handleTap)] autorelease];
[theView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

If I debug the property gestureRecognizers of the view it shows the gesture recognizer object. But when I tap inside the view it doesn't work.

The same code using an UIImageView works perfect, any ideas why doesn't work in UIView?

UPDATED:

An example class.

```
@implementation ExampleClass

- (UIView *)getViewInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithRect:rect];
    [theView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                    initWithTarget:self 
                                    action:@selector(handleTap)] 
                                   autorelease];
    [aText addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    return theView;
}

- (UIImageView *)getImageViewInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImageView *theView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithRect:rect];
    [theView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                        initWithTarget:self 
                                                action:@selector(handleTap)] 
                                   autorelease];
    [theView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    return [theView autorelease];    
}

- (void)handleTap
{
    NSLog(@"Tap Handled!!", nil);
}

@end
```

UPDATED 2:

Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to all subviews of theView don't fix the problem...

FIX IT!!!

OK!! The problem was the CGRect for theView, it had the width set to 0.0!!!

Comment: what is your handleTap function looking like?   
Are you using a gestureRecognizer in the Superview of theView, that could catch the gesture?

Comment: handleTap is a method of the same class where the above code live. From this scoop I can call it without problems with [self handleTap].

Comment: Are you saying that if you replaced `UIView` with `UIImageview` in the code snippet above it works?

Comment: That... shouldn't be. Show more code :)

Comment: @freespace See the updated, is a C&P code from project (I can't show more). This appears a joke!! :-S

Comment: How are they added to your view hierarchy?

Comment: `[someViewController.view addSubview:[exampleInstance getViewInRect:rect]]`

Comment: This makes no sense :( Can you make a bare-bones project that reproduces this behaviour without giving anything about your project away? If you add the tap recognizer to self.view does THAT work?

Comment: I've created an isolated project only for this issue and works perfectly (including subviews). I have the problem in other part of the original project...but I don't know where. I will continue investigating... thanks to all!

Comment: Are you using a gestureRecognizer in the Superview of theView, that could catch the gesture?

Comment: @Seega: No, I'm not using any type of gestureRecognizer or userInteractionEnabled in the superview...

Answer (score 19):

Did you try this?

```
[view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare theview as ivar in .h file. Synthesize and then call it like this:

```
[self.theview setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

Don't forget to alloc and init that theview in viewDidLoad method.

That's it.